# Generate access token without User Interaction for publish-actions

Tags: c#, facebook

I want to post an update to my own facebook page from a .NET service.   I can make a FB App and that wants 'publish-actions' and 'manage_pages'.   But how can I get an accessToken in code. The posts would be infrequent so I don't mind generating a new access token each time, but I need it done by the service without any interaction from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following scenario 5 of https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ should allow you to authorize once as a user and then use the page token indefinitely without any need to re-authorize.

> Exchange the short-lived user access token for a long-lived access token using the endpoint and steps explained earlier. By using a long-lived user access token, querying the [User ID]/accounts endpoint will now provide page access tokens that do not expire for pages that a user manages. This will also apply when querying with a non-expiring user access token obtained through the deprecated offline_access permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/